# Открыть панель уведомлений и быстрые настройки

Tags: android

Каким образом можно открыть панель уведомлений, а также быстрые настройки, которые находятся над уведомлениями?

[image: Скриншот быстрых настроек]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На помощь приходит рефлексия

```
Object sbservice = getSystemService( "statusbar" );
Class<?> statusbarManager = Class.forName( "android.app.StatusBarManager" );
Method showsb;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
showsb = statusbarManager.getMethod("expandSettingsPanel");
}
else {
showsb = statusbarManager.getMethod("expand");
}
showsb.invoke( sbservice );
```

Разрешение в манифесте

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />
```

**Объясняю**

Начиная с API 17 метод `expand` был заменен на `expandNotificationsPanel` для открытия панели уведомлений и `expandSettingsPanel` для открытия быстрых настроек.

Вот список всех методов `StatusBarManager` (API >= 17). Так, для общего развития

```
collapsePanels //задвигает шторку

disable //запретить выдвигать шторку. даже не пытайтесь. Метод требует разрешения STATUS_BAR, которое выдаётся только системным приложениям

expandNotificationsPanel //открывает шторку уведомлений

expandSettingsPanel //открывает быстрые настройки

removeIcon //Используется системой для удаления значков на статусбаре

setIcon //Используется системой для установки значков на статусбаре

setIconVisibility //используется системой для установки видимости значков на статусбаре

windowStateToString //возвращает состояние (скрыт, открыт, свернут)
```

Comment: Извиняюсь, если вопрос глупый, но где взять исходники StatusBarManager?

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/4.4_r1-robolectric-1/android/app/StatusBarManager.java или если не хотите возиться то могу добавить в ответ вариант с рефлексией

Comment: Я уже раз 10 попробовал, так и не смог сделать... Неужели Google не могли сделать это просто?

Comment: `StatusBarManager` не может поставляться в SDK по той причине, что разработчики системного ПО, бывает, его пишут по разному.

Comment: Обновил ответ .

Comment: Я поместил всё в try и перед началом void поместил @SuppressWarnings("WrongConstant") и всё заработало. Спасибо

Comment: @ГуАлСе, Не за что!